# Creating a virtual merged groups

Tags: mysql

I am trying to better understand what I need to do for my next project.

I have 3 db tables.

```
t1 (book)
-----------
id  
project_id  
label


t2 (box)
-----------
id  
project_id  
creator_id  
label

t3 (how they relate to each other)
-----------
id  
box_id  
book_id     
project_id  
user_id

t1.id = t3.boo_id
t2.id = t3.box_id
t2.creator_id = t3.user_id
```

Books can be placed inside boxes and the boxes are labeled. My script keeps count of the totals of books per boxes. It works fine, until different users start placing same books into boxes and naming them differently, but close.

I would like to be able to implement some sort of "virtual merge" where I could select several similar box labels, like: *miscellaneous*, *Misc* and *misc.*, assign my own label, say *MISC* and have the script treat it as if books in those 3 boxes were inside this new one.

Not really sure how to do that. I don't want to merge those permanently. I'll eventually add a functionality to remove some "boxes" from merged groups and have the script recalculate the totals.

I think I need to add a new table:

```
t4
----------
id 
box_id
label
```

Currently my script grabs the boxes info like this:

```
SELECT id, label
FROM t2
WHERE project_id = $project_id
ORDER BY id
```

books like this

```
SELECT id, label
FROM t1
WHERE project_id = $project_id
ORDER BY id
```

and total counts like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
FROM t3
WHERE project_id = $project_id
```

How would I rewrite the query given that there may or may not be a "merged group"?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You seem to have redundant information in t3, in that a box appears to belong to a single project and creator (per t2), which would render project_id and user_id redundant in t3.

Comment: t3 contains only information of how books, from t1 relate to boxes in t2. Basically which book was placed in which box and by which user. t3 only is used by admin who can see all transaction history with totals. t2 data is created by users.

Answer (score 0):

So users are filling out their own labels in some type of form or something? I would suggest what you were saying with creating a new table set up: id, box_id, labels (with an s, and as a text field). Store all of the acceptable label names in the labels column (so say box id 1 was for all miscellaneous type of boxes you would add into the new table box_id = 1, labels = "misc, miscellaneous, misc., extra, other, unknown" etc. Then when a user creates a new label, cross reference it with all of the acceptable labels for all of the boxes. If there is a match, pull out the exact box_id from the table. The re-assigning the books to the appropriate box would be as books are put into this box, not after they are put in their own box and then trying to be merged.

I think it might include something like this

```
$box_label = $_POST['label'];

$getrelatedboxes = mysql_query("SELECT box_id, MATCH(labels) AGAINST('$box_label' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relation FROM newtable HAVING relation > 0 ORDER BY relation DESC LIMIT 1");
$related_boxes = mysql_num_rows($getrelatedpages);

if($related_boxes){

$box_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrelatedboxes);

// insert books into that box

}
else {
// create new label and insert those books into that box
}
```